# Sturm-Liouville Regular problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, sturm-liouville

I'm looking at the following S-L ODE:

$\frac{d}{dx} \left[e^{ix} f'(x)\right] + e^{ix} \lambda f(x) = 0$,

where $i$ is the complex number, and $\lambda$ denotes the eigenvalues. However, this can only have real eigenvalues if the problem is regular, i.e., that somehow, one has to show that $e^{ix} > 0$ over some interval. As this is a complex function, I'm having difficulty showing this.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is the ODE defined over a specific interval? Do you have any boundary conditions?

Comment: I was considering any interval / BCs for which this problem could be considered regular.

Comment: I was considering any interval / BCs for which this problem could be considered regular. Perhaps, even coming up with a way to define such an interval could be useful. @Dmoreno

Comment: Your ODE is reducible to $f'' + \mathrm{i} f' + \lambda f =0$, so its solution is $f = A \mathrm{e}^{s_1 x} + B \mathrm{e}^{s_2 x}$, with $s_{1,2}$ complex numbers. I'm afraid I can't say anything else about $\lambda$ without having any boundary conditions.

Comment: Hi @Dmoreno Suppose we have Dirichlet B.C's, say, f(a) = f(b) = 0. Is there a way to show that the eigenvalues would be real?

Comment: Well, if that happens to be the case, then you can multiply throughout by $f^{*}$ and integrate by parts to solve for $\lambda$, which yields $\lambda = \int^{b}_{a} \mathrm{e}^{ix} |f'|^2 \, \mathrm{d}x / \int^{b}_{a} \mathrm{e}^{ix} |f|^2 \, \mathrm{d}x $. I think you can prove that the integral is always real for any $f$, but I'm not sure how to go about that. Please let me know if you want me to post this as an answer. If $f = \exp(\mathrm{i} s x)$, then it turns out that $\lambda = |s|^2$.

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful. Yes, if you can post this as an answer, I will upvote it. :)

Comment: You're welcome, glad to help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If homogenous Dirichlet boundary conditions are available, then multiplying by the complex conjugate of $f$ and integrating by parts once yields

$$\lambda = \frac{\displaystyle\int^{b}_{a} \mathrm{e}^{ix} |f'|^2 \, \mathrm{d}x}{\displaystyle\int^{b}_{a} \mathrm{e}^{ix} |f|^2 \, \mathrm{d}x}$$

For $f= \mathrm{e}^{i sx}$, which is the solution to any linear operator, the fraction above turns out to be real. Moreover, $\lambda = |s|^2$.